# Failed to load DevAppEngineWebAppContext (App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am not sure if this error is the one causing my gwt-app engine application not to load and get `HTTP Error 503` when accessed during debug mode:

```
WARNING: Failed startup of context 
com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext
```

If this is the cause, then in what way I can fix this?

Comment: This is a consequence (failure of context startup), not the cause. Posting a full stack trace might help you get an answer.